# Sandbox Mode for CCAvenue payment gateway in Android Application

Tags: android, android-studio, payment-gateway, sandbox

Is there any Sandbox mode or Test Account SDK for CCAvenue PG in android?

If Yes then provide any Link or tell me the other way to implement CCAvenue PG in my App as a Test Account.

I've tried everything including Docs and Integration kit by CCAvenue but they are asking for MerchantID and Access code which will be provided after paying for the Merchant Account.

I just want to get a sandbox or test account for my App.

They provided me a Link for the Docs and I want to implement Seamless Account for my App.

Link for the Docs & Kit:-
https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/IntegrationKits-WebMobile.rar

Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope it works**

You have to implement your own class with the codes given in the kit and just have to call via intent and pass the required params.
for test account contact CCAvenue team for test merchant ID and RSA URL.

Comment: Nice Amaresh, your Android skills are as sharp as PHP.